# ExtJS & Internet Explorer: Layout corruption with scrollbars

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, layout, extjs, corruption

I am having some problems with Internet Explorer. I have a `Window` with one `Fieldset` containing a few `Components` - all ExtJS elements.

The window is resizable and I **want** the scrollbars to appear when the user resizes the window to a size smaller than the size required to show its contents.

This works fine in FireFox 3.6.x, but when using IE7 or IE8 I get the following result:

[image: Corrupted layout in Internet Explorer]

**Why do I get this result in Internet Explorer and shouldn't it be possible to do what I want?**

The code used to generate the above result is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    <title>Online example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/resources/css/ext-all.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/adapter/ext/ext-base.js"></script>     

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/ext-all.js"></script>    

</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

Ext.onReady(function(){

    MyWindow = Ext.extend(Ext.Window, {         
        resizable: true,
        closable: true,
        width: 400,
        closeAction: 'hide',                        
        title: 'Window',
        autoScroll: true,
        layout: 'fit',

        initComponent: function () {

            var config = {
                items:
                [
                    {
                        xtype: 'fieldset',
                        title: 'Fieldset',
                        layout: 'form',
                        items:
                        [
                            {
                                xtype: 'numberfield',                                                                                                       
                                fieldLabel: 'Label'                                    
                            }, {
                                xtype: 'checkbox',
                                fieldLabel: 'Label',
                                checked: true                                    
                            }, {
                                xtype: 'checkbox',
                                fieldLabel: 'Label',
                                checked: true                                    
                            }, {
                                xtype: 'checkbox',
                                fieldLabel: 'Label',
                                checked: true                                    
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }

            Ext.apply(this, config);

            // Config object has already been applied to 'this' so properties can 
            // be overriden here or new properties (e.g. items, tools, buttons) 
            // can be added, eg:

            // Call parent (required)
            MyWindow.superclass.initComponent.apply(this, arguments);
        }   
    });

    AWindow = new MyWindow();
    AWindow.show();
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I know that this question is very similar to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923435/extjs-ie7-rendering-problems-with-simple-window) of mine, but I hope this time I'm more clear in what I am asking for. - And it relates to both IE7 and IE8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that when giving the window:

```
bodyStyle: 'position:relative;'
```

the *FieldSet* stays inside the window. Why this is needed I don't know, neither how to set this attribute a more *Extjs'y* way.

If you have any comments, I welcome them in hope of enlightment :)

Answer (score 1):

I got this example working by wrapping the fieldset in a panel, and moving the autoscroll from the window to the panel:

```
MyWindow = Ext.extend(Ext.Window, {         
        resizable: true,
        closable: true,
        width: 400,
        height: 200,
        closeAction: 'hide',                        
        title: 'Window',
        layout: 'fit',

        initComponent: function () {

            var config = {
                items: {
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    autoScroll: true,
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'fieldset',
                            title: 'Fieldset',
                            layout: 'form',
                            items:
                            [
                                {
                                    xtype: 'numberfield',                                                                                                       
                                    fieldLabel: 'Label'                                    
                                }, {
                                    xtype: 'checkbox',
                                    fieldLabel: 'Label',
                                    checked: true                                    
                                }, {
                                    xtype: 'checkbox',
                                    fieldLabel: 'Label',
                                    checked: true                                    
                                }, {
                                    xtype: 'checkbox',
                                    fieldLabel: 'Label',
                                    checked: true                                    
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }

            Ext.apply(this, config);

            // Config object has already been applied to 'this' so properties can 
            // be overriden here or new properties (e.g. items, tools, buttons) 
            // can be added, eg:

            // Call parent (required)
            MyWindow.superclass.initComponent.apply(this, arguments);
        }   
    });

    AWindow = new MyWindow();
    AWindow.show();
});
```

Couple notes:

- I had to give the window some **height** in order for it to show anything when opened
- Your original example works well in "Quirks Mode", which you can get by removing the DOCTYPE declaration at the top of your file.